# Share dialog: "Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later."

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm facing a reproducible issue with the share dialog:

When creating a new file with Editey I get the error message above. When reloading the page it still does not work.

But when opening the same file from Drive in another browser tab it works fine - even in the original tab that was not working before.

Is there anything I can do to make sharing work for new files?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Editey has the share button that's inside of a frame. We have `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` policy for the wigdets that is not allowing to use them inside of a frame for security reasons.

Share button should not be inside of a frame.

Comment: This is strange because it works flawlessly when opening the file from Drive. The page is identical for both cases. In face I do a redirect when creating a new file so it is both the same URL / page source.