# Google Sharing API Leads to 500 Error and "Sharing is Unavailable" Message

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am attempting to set up the sharing ability on a web application that I am making. I have followed the steps on [Google's Drive Sharing Instruction Page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app) to the best of my ability. However, when I click the button, I get the expected popup, but with the message "Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later."

The code I have is slightly different, as the `init` function name is being used elsewhere. The code I have is:

```
function initializeGoogleApis() {
    /*
    self._shareClient = {
        'showSettingsDialog': function() {
            devConsole.warning(0, "The sharing ability has not yet been implemented.");
        }
    };*/

    gapi.load('drive-share', function() {    
        self._shareClient = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient();
        self._shareClient.setOAuthToken(self.clientId);
        self._shareClient.setItemIds(self.realtimeUtils.getParam("id"));
    });


}
```

Note the commented section. I had this to insure that the 'share' button on my page is loaded properly and calling the function, which it is. As explained in the title, when I click the button, I get a 500 error in the console.

At the bottom of the Google page listed above, it says the following:

- The user is signed in to Google  -->  I have done this
- The user has installed your app  -->  I don't know about this. For all other functionality, I only have to visit the site, so I am not sure what the difference here is.
- The URL of the page that launches the dialog must have the same origin as the Open URL registered for the app  -->  I think I have this done. I followed the link on the page ([here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#open_url)) and verified ownership.

I am also testing on the actual host, not on `localhost` as it states this will not work.

All the same, I get the following error:

```
GET https://drive.google.com/sharing/share?id=xxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx8&fore…
d=false&client=postMessage&embedOrigin=http://www.example.com 500 ()
    _.k.$l @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:651
    _.k.S @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:651
    _.k.Ql @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:794
    ys.kc @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:791
    Ts.OV @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:822
    Zs @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:814
    FM @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:818
    Ts.Ph @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:818
    pt.Na @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:829
    onclick @ ?id=xxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:97
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612838/share-dialog-sorry-sharing-is-unavailable-at-this-time-please-try-again-late and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264778/google-drive-unable-to-share

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and I just looked at both. The button is not in a frame, and I tested it with both a new account, a new browser, and a new computer. None of these fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are passing in your clientID instead of your OAuth token.

Comment: Okay, until reading that, I thought those were identical. Any idea on how I pass in the OAuth token?

Comment: I have modified the line to "s.setOAuthToken(gapi.auth.getToken());", but that did not appear to help